# resign keyboard in UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, keyboard, iphone-keypad

I'm working with storyboards on iOS 5 and have a simple screen that has a `UITextField` on it. I want to dismiss the keyboard when the user hits "Return". I followed other suggestions such as having my controller implements the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol and implements `textFieldShouldReturn:` as follows:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [questionField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

However I see that this method is never called. I have set the controller of my view in storyboarding to my custom `UIViewController`.

I also tried a different implementation where I create an `IBAction` called `dismissKeyboard` but oddly I can't connect the `Did Exit` action to my `UITextField`.

Any ideas?

Update : So the problem seems to be that I'm using a UITextView and not a UITextField. I wanted a large area for the text to be entered. When I change the entry field to a UITextField it works fine. Any ideas on how to make it work with a UITextView?

Comment: have you set `questionField.delegate = self` where `self` could be the controller where you created your `UItextField`? Also try to implement `textFieldDidEndEditing:`. This method is called whenever the editing session is finished (for example when the user closes the keyboard).

Answer (score 0):

You should connect the dismiss method to the text field's `Did End Editing` action.

Comment: I tried doing that but oddly when i select the action uner 'Received Actions' and hover over the uitextfield it does not get highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution to resign the keyboard for a UITextView is to implement shouldChangeTextInRange.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the keyboard to dismiss when tap the return key for the textview use this delegate function,

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text {

    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: In this code when we paste text with 2 paragraph then it will not paste data